# Split 2D array to array with new rows

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, datatable, split

I have 2d array with next values.

```
1 t\2 3
2 f\5 b
4 f\b\g 6 8\9
```

After split array by `\` I want receive

```
1 t 3
1 2 3
2 f b
2 5 b
4 f 6 8
4 f 6 9
4 b 6 8 
4 b 6 9
4 g 6 8 
4 g 6 9
```

I tried this but it doesn't achieve it:

```
var result = row.Table.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => r == row)
        .SelectMany(r => this.projectMapping.Select(pm => r[pm.OriginalName]
        .ToString()
        .Split(this.separator, StringSplitOptions.None)));
```

Comment: 2d array with next values.?? and what is this format ?1 t\2 3
2 f\5 b

Comment: Please show an example of how you populate such an array

Comment: this is examples values in datarow

Comment: List<string[]> row = new List<string[]>()
            {
                new string[] { "1", "t/2", "3" },
                new string[] { "2", "f/5", "b"}
            };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an extension method that produces combinations of sequences. This method can be used to obtain your result.

First, each array in the 2D array must be converted to 2D arrays themselves:

```
var array = new[]
{
    new[] {"1", @"t\2", "3"},
    new[] {"2", @"f\5", "b"},
    new[] {"4", @"f\b\g", "6", @"8\9"},
};
var splitted = array.Select(a => a.Aggregate(new List<List<string>>(),
    (seed, c) =>
        {
            seed.Add(c.Split(@"\".ToCharArray()).ToList());
            return seed;
        }));
```

Now `splitted` is a sequence of 2D arrays that each have to be combined. To visualize it, the first element of this sequence is:

```
[1], [t,2], [3]
```

The extension methods used are:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combine<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> listOfLists)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> seed = new List<List<T>> { new List<T>() };
        return listOfLists.Aggregate(seed, (r, list) => 
            r.SelectMany(a => list.Select(x => a.Append(x))));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, params T[] elements)
    {
        return list == null ? elements : list.Concat(elements);
    }
}
```

Using the `Combine` method, the desired result can be obtained by

```
var result = splitted.SelectMany(s => s.Combine());
```

And to visualize it:

```
foreach (var element in result.Select(x => string.Join(", ", x)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Giving:

```
1, t, 3
1, 2, 3
2, f, b
2, 5, b
4, f, 6, 8
4, f, 6, 9
4, b, 6, 8
4, b, 6, 9
4, g, 6, 8
4, g, 6, 9
```

The idea of the `Combine` method is that for each sequence entering it, combinations are built cumulatively. Taking the first sequence, `[1], [t,2], [3]`, the result of the first aggregation cycle is `[1,t]` and `[1,2]`. Each of these combined with `[3]` produces `[1,t,3]` and `[1,2,3]`.